# Edit inline in table in index view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use the following code to display the table rows 
for every row there is edit and delete button ,what i want to do is 
when I click on edit for specific row change the row from display only
to editable row (instead of navigating to other page for edit),how should I do that?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox1)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="data-table">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox1)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

This is how the table look like

[image]

Ive try to change the code to something like this but I got following errors:

```
     <tbody id="data-table">

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
            <tr>
                if (Model[i].Id == ViewBag.SelectedID)
                {
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model=> model[i].name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m=> m[i].checkBox1)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">Save</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                </td>
                }
                }
                else
                {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m[i].checkBox1)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.Id })
                </td>
                }
            </tr>
}
```

**The error is in statments:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].name) and

 @Html.EditorFor(m=> m[i]checkBox1)
```

try specifing the arguments explicitly,any idea?

Comment: Have you tried anything? with jQuery you could replace all the text with inputs, but what you are asking is not a trivial task.

Comment: @cale_b- this is the reason that i open this message to get some example which can help since i didnt find any similar example in the web...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code

Below function make row editable

```
var nCurrentEdit = 0;
$('#data-table').on('click', '.btnCustomEdit', function () {
    nCurrentEdit = $(this).attr("id");

    var oTR = $(this).parents("tr").first();

    var sText = '<input type="text" value="' + oTR.find("td:nth-child(1)").text().trim() + '" />';
    oTR.find("td:nth-child(1)").html(sText);
    oTR.find(":disabled").prop("disabled", false);

    if (oTR.find("#btnsubmit").length == 0)
        oTR.find("td:last").append("<input id='btnUpdate' type='submit' value='Update' class='btn btn-default'>");

    oTR.find("td:last a").hide();

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Following function update the record and convert the row normal from editable mode.

```
$('#data-table').on('click', '#btnUpdate', function () {
    var postData = {
        id : nCurrentEdit,
        name: $("#name").val(),
        checkBox1: $("#checkBox1").val(),
        checkBox2: $("#checkBox2").val(),
        checkBox3: $("#checkBox3").val()
    };

    $.post('@Url.Action("AjaxEdit", "Roles")', postData, null);

    var sNewText = $(this).parents("tr").first().find("td:first input").val();
    $(this).parents("tr").first().find("td:first").append(sNewText);
    $(this).parents("tr").first().find("td:first input").remove();
    $(this).parents("tr").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled", true);

    $(this).parent().find("a").show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use jEditable http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable and intagrate it with your table.

Maybe you can use DataTables too with jEditable if it's fits your project, something like http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/editable.html